# cqlsh connection error: unable to connect to any servers

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I have just installed cql and cassandra on my Mac OS X by running the following commands via terminal:

```
pip install cql
pip install cassandra-driver
brew install cassandra
```

And then I started cassandra by running `brew services start cassandra`. Then I tried to run `cqlsh` but was returned with the following error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})
```

May I know what could have caused this, and how may I go about solving this problem? Thank you!

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11850

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra may not be running in your environment. if you execute `nodetool status`, it should be able to return the information of the cluster and nodes included in it. If it returns an exception, you will need to look at the error logs and troubleshoot. The default location of the logs is `/usr/local/var/log/cassandra`

Comment: Just found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/hkhamm/a9a2b45dd749e5d3b3ae) with instructions to install and start Cassandra for Mac OS X that may be helpful for you

Comment: i executed nodetool status getting exception and even that location is not there

Comment: what exception are you getting? is the database running?

Comment: Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
when i run cqlsh

Comment: for nodetool status
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.

Comment: the service may not be running, you can look up for the process with 'ps -efa | grep cassandra' in linux; also the logs (cassandra/system.log) can give you information. if the service is running, you can verify if the cassandra.yaml is set to listen to 127.0.0.1, out of the port is open. You should look for more questions with the specific settings similar to your setup, if there are no similar questions, please post a new question giving information of your operating system, database configuration, number of nodes, engine version, and the steps that you have already taken to investigate

Comment: cassandra/system.log permissions was denied and  'ps -efa | grep cassandra' processing is running ps -efa | grep cassandra
umapathi  8661  8645  0 10:16 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto cassandra